# Get post list in same category

Tags: infinite-scroll

I have a code that loads the next post infinitely at the end of each post. Currently, the next post is picked at random. I would like the next post to be restricted to the category of the current post.

In an attempt, I have created a custom field 'scrollcat' and assigned same value to all post belonging to a category.

However, the next post is still jumping from the category of the current post to a different one. All the posts in the next one are exhausted before moving into another. I would like all the posts in the category of the current one to be exhausted first before going to another category.

```
    $listed_posts = isset($_POST["listed_posts"]) && !empty($_POST["listed_posts"]) && is_array($_POST["listed_posts"]) ? $this->isrp_ll_sanitize_post_ids($_POST["listed_posts"]) : array();
    $response = false;

    // Assuming you have the current post ID stored in $current_post_id
    $current_post_id = get_the_ID(); // Retrieve the current post ID

    $current_post_categories = wp_get_post_categories($current_post_id);
    $category_slug = '';

    if (!empty($current_post_categories)) {
        // Get the first category slug (assuming there's only one category per post)
        $category_slug = get_category($current_post_categories[0])->slug;
    }

    // Get all posts within the category of the current post
    $category_posts_args = array(
        "posts_per_page" => -1,
        "post_type" => "post",
        "post_status" => "publish",
        "category_name" => $category_slug,
        "exclude" => $listed_posts,
        "orderby" => "meta_value_num",
        "meta_key" => "scrollcat"
    );
    $category_posts = get_posts($category_posts_args);

    // Check if there are any remaining posts within the category
    if (!empty($category_posts)) {
        // Get the first post from the category
        $next_post = array_shift($category_posts);

        $response = new stdClass;
        $response->post_id = $next_post->ID;
        $response->permalink = get_permalink($response->post_id);
    } else {
        // If no posts remaining in the category, retrieve a random post from any category
        $all_posts_args = array(
            "posts_per_page" => 1,
            "post_type" => "post",
            "post_status" => "publish",
            "exclude" => $listed_posts,
            "orderby" => "meta_value_num",
            "meta_key" => "scrollcat"
        );
        $all_posts = get_posts($all_posts_args);

        if (!empty($all_posts)) {
            $response = new stdClass;
            $response->post_id = $all_posts[0]->ID;
            $response->permalink = get_permalink($response->post_id);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    die("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a system to load the next post within the same category can indeed be achieved with modifications to your existing code. Here's how I think you should modify it so it works:

```
// Assuming you have the current post ID stored in $current_post_id
$current_post_id = get_the_ID(); // Retrieve the current post ID
$current_post_categories = wp_get_post_categories($current_post_id);
$listed_posts = isset($_POST["listed_posts"]) && !empty($_POST["listed_posts"]) && is_array($_POST["listed_posts"]) ? $this->isrp_ll_sanitize_post_ids($_POST["listed_posts"]) : array();

$next_post = null;

if (!empty($current_post_categories)) {
    // Get the first category slug (assuming there's only one category per post)
    $category_id = $current_post_categories[0];

    $args = array(
        'category' => $category_id,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'exclude' => $listed_posts,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $next_post = get_posts($args);
}

// If no next post within the category, get a random post.
if (!$next_post) {
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'exclude' => $listed_posts,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $next_post = get_posts($args);
}

$response = false;
if (!empty($next_post)) {
    $next_post = $next_post[0]; // get_posts returns array, get first post from it
    $response = new stdClass;
    $response->post_id = $next_post->ID;
    $response->permalink = get_permalink($response->post_id);
}

echo json_encode($response);
die("");
```

This code first attempts to fetch a next post from the same category. If none is found (or the current post has no category), it retrieves a random post. Note that this assumes that your posts could belong to multiple categories but you're interested only in the first one.

Please replace 'date' and 'DESC' in the 'orderby' and 'order' arguments if you need a different sorting criterion.

And of course, I haven't totally tested this code. So feel free to do tweaks to it as necessary.